# position:fixed not working in chrome 22

Tags: google-chrome, css-position

i'm new with html5 and css3. I released my first website last month and now i found out that it's not working well in the new chrome version (22): All the fixed elements are no longer fixed... The navigation bar on the top of the screen for example. it was fine only a week ago and i have no idea why now it's not.
This is the website: [www.biofilter.co.il](http://www.biofilter.co.il)

As far as i can tell, it's still working fine in Firefox and IE.

Does anyone has an idea what's going on and what could be the reason?

Comment: Chrome was developed recently, I think the new version of Chrome is incompatible with your current version.

Comment: I understand that z-index works differently in chrome 22 but that's not the problem in my site. position:fixed doesn't work at all...

Comment: Maybe another rule overwrites your rule regarding the position. Try !important and let me know what the result is.

Comment: I tried it but !important isn't changing anything... a week ago my site code was the same and everything was working just fine in chrome. I'm almost sure that it has something to do with the new chrome version.

Comment: @HadarWeiss: It seems to work fine in Chrome 22.0.1229.79. The top and side navigations are fixed on the browser view.

Comment: Yeah, i have a same problem as you do. still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I can confirm this still happens on Chrome 27 / Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely caused by Chrome reworking how `position:fixed` elements handle *stacking* of `z-index`. The change was made for `Chrome v22` so if you built on v21 and use `position:fixed`, you might have a problem.

They suggested testing by hitting the Chrome special URL `about:flags` in the browser, and setting `Fixed position elements create stacking contexts.` to true (for v22+) or false (for v21).

It is possible to rework your CSS by ensuring `position:fixed` elements are stacking correctly. Unfortunately, it is a little complicated so recommend you read these for better explanation:

- [Stacking changes coming to position:fixed elements](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements)
- [Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts](https://plus.google.com/103238735625031210015/posts/PXDRAukeZvd)