# Position Fixed doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, position, z-index

I'm creating these overlay previous and next arrows, like the ones on this website - http://www.usatoday.com

And the problem I'm getting is in Chrome, the arrows won't stay fixed, when I scroll down the page the arrows go up with the page and you can't see them anymore. The weird thing is that in Firefox they work and stay at top: 45% position: fixed all the time like they should. 
Here is a screenshot on how it works in ff: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vsrv874c3urlqs/firefox.PNG

and here is chrome: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgr2zhkcnohykgj/chrome.PNG

The html for the arrows:

```
 <div class="overlay-arrows">
        <div class="front-arrow-wrapper">
            <a href="#" rel="prev" class="prev-link">
                <div class="prev-icon">
                </div>
                <div class="prev-overlay">
                    <span class="categ-next">Category for prev</span>
                    <p>Title of the post for prev</p>
                </div>          
            </a>
            <a href="#" rel="next" class="next-link" >
                <div class="next-icon">
                </div>
                <div class="next-overlay">
                    <span class="categ-next">Category for next</span>
                    <p>Title of the post for next</p>
                </div>              
            </a>
        </div> <!--end .front-arrow-wrapper -->
    </div> <!--end overlay-arrows -->
```

And CSS:

```
.overlay-arrows{
    position: fixed;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: visible;
}
.front-arrow-wrapper{
width: 1104px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.prev-link{
left: 0;
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
}
.next-link{
right: 0;
float: right;
text-decoration: none;
}   
.prev-icon{
  background: url(../img/prev.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
  height: 77px;
  width: 45px;
float: left;
}
.next-icon{
  background: url(../img/next.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
  height: 77px;
float: right;
  width: 45px;
}
.next-overlay, .prev-overlay{
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
width: 250px;
width: 250px;
height: 77px;
color: #F16C14;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}   
.next-link:hover>.next-icon{
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  background: url(../img/next-hover.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
}
.next-link:hover>.next-overlay{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  opacity: 10;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: This code gives me vertically centered arrows in Chrome on Mac and Windows (http://jsfiddle.net/Lj3RG/). Is there a containing element around the arrows causing problems, or any javascript on the page that changes these styles?

Comment: I found that there are 3 files that when I disable them the arrows work, but I need them for an article slider on the page. https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtpflj57yxqmed4/dan.css https://www.dropbox.com/s/db2wdzll4p1fmw6/jquery.bxslider.css https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5ceq3yoinxqzct/jquery.validate.min.js I can't imagine what could be that only affects the arrows in chrome and in firefox they work perfectly.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem, so I'd guess it's styling on the containing elements. Either wrappers for the arrows, or wrappers for the content. I found other reports of chrome position:fixed issues. You could try `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` on the fixed element - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068361/chrome-positionfixed-inside-positionabsolute-breaking-with-iframe-video or maybe investigate the z-index stacking context - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781115/positionfixed-not-working-in-chrome-22 ?

Comment: I used -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); and it worked. THANKS!! you totally saved me :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used cjspurg method and it worked. Thanks again!

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: this gives you cancer of dealing with fixed elements placed inside the element on which you will apply -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); property. You will find that fixed no longer works on the elements inside the container element.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/fixed-position-z-index-does-not-work-in-chrome/ you can't use Z-index on background images which could be part of the issue there's an example on that post that may help you it's also here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iKljy ( you have to sign up for an account to see it, but it looks like it could help you).