# Position fixed does not work in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In my website and in this [page](http://www.3ag.ir/contact.html) I have a background image for my page. This background image must be fixed. This page works correctly in Firefox, but doesn't work in Google Chrome . the background image css is like this :

```
.aboutBG {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

I searched around the web and find some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117737/position-fixed-doesnt-work-in-chrome) for using code like below :

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: works fine in chrome: Version 34.0.1847.116

Comment: My chrome version is 34.0.1847.116 but when page scroll the image go to up and not fix. but in Firefox image is fixed.

Comment: I'm sorry you're right! my browser window was to big..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not apply background image to div make some good logic

Your css should be looks like

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://justbeecosmetics.com/img/headImage.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#blank{
    height:80%;
}

#top{
    height: 70%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#bottom{
    height:50%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Please check the fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/jdmitz/V8WqE/

You have added to wrong position

Answer (score 0):

Easier would be to **add**:

```
#container {
   background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```