# Position fixed not working as expected in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

I am in the process of building a homepage for a client whereby they want each section to scroll over the other.

This works as expected, on the whole, except for any panel directly under the carousel. You can view a preview of the page here: Link now unavailable.

The page works as expected in Firefox and IE11. The issue is prevalent in Chrome and Chrome Canary.

The issue is that the panel under the carousel doesn't stay fixed in the view and scrolls along with the page scrolling, unlike the panels below it which stay anchored to the top of the page when scrolled to the top.

Only one panel is position:fixed at any one time due to performance issues in Chrome when having more than one fixed at any given time.

I'm stumped on how to fix this issue and looking to the community for some assistance... thanks in advance!

Andi

Comment: How does the failing HTML look?

Comment: Post the HTML, CSS and any code involved please

Comment: Try this: http://codepen.io/mangopearuk/pen/deJCy?editors=010

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my issue was simple.

If I add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to my `.home-panel` the panels behave as expected.

This was partly derived from the answer on: [Position Fixed doesn't work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117737/position-fixed-doesnt-work-in-chrome?rq=1)